# Android Dashboard Layout with TabHost

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have search and could seem to find anything close to the issue I am having so I figured I would ask.
I have a Dashboard layout

[image]

This is all working correctly

What I want to do is have it work as shown below ( I have the Tabhost defined but I had to setup the class to extend TabActivity which breaks the ActionBar navigation )

[image]

The tabs correctly switch but it will not allow me to use any of the buttons on the action bar, and its not pulling the information correctly like it should be

[image]

the above works correctly.  So I guess my question is how can I correctly add the TabHost to my classes and also have it Extend or Implement the Dashboard code? I have tried extends TabActivity implements Dashboard with no luck.

Here is my code thus far

Dashboard.java

```
 package com.ondrovic.bbym;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.res.Configuration;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public abstract class Dashboard extends Activity {
 public static final boolean usePrettyGoodSolution = false;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

public void onClickHome(View v) {
    goHome(this);
}

public void onClickUpdate(View v) {
    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Update.class));
}

public void onClickAbout(View v) {
    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class));
}

public void goHome(Context context) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutID) {
    if (!usePrettyGoodSolution) {
        super.setContentView(layoutID);
        return;
    }

    Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();
    int size = c.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
    boolean isLarge = (size == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
    boolean isXLarge = (size == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);
    boolean addFrame = isLarge || isXLarge;

    // if (isLarge) System.out.println ("Large screen");
    // if (isXLarge) System.out.println ("XLarge screen");

    int finalLayoutId = addFrame ? R.layout.large : layoutID;
    super.setContentView(finalLayoutId);

    if (addFrame) {
        LinearLayout frameView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        if (frameView != null) {

            // If the frameView is there, inflate the layout given as an
            // argument.
            // Attach it as a child to the frameView.
            LayoutInflater li = ((Activity) this).getLayoutInflater();
            View childView = li.inflate(layoutID, null);
            if (childView != null) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0F);
                frameView.addView(childView, lp);
                // childView.setBackgroundResource (R.color.background1);
            }

        }
    }
}

public void setTitleFromActivityLabel(int textViewID) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(textViewID);
    if (tv !=null) {
        tv.setText(getTitle());
    }
}

}
```

Individual.java

```
 package com.ondrovic.bbym;

 import android.app.TabActivity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TabHost;
 import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class Individual extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedSate) {
    super.onCreate(savedSate);
    setContentView(R.layout.individual);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabSpec attspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ATT");
    attspec.setIndicator("AT&T", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_att_tab));
    Intent attIntent = new Intent(this, Individual_ATT.class);
    attspec.setContent(attIntent);

    TabSpec sprspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("SPRINT");
    sprspec.setIndicator("SPRINT", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_sprint_tab));
    Intent sprIntent = new Intent(this, Individual_SPRINT.class);
    sprspec.setContent(sprIntent);

    TabSpec vzwspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("VERIZON");
    vzwspec.setIndicator("VERIZON", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_verizon_tab));
    Intent vzwIntent = new Intent(this, Individual_VERIZON.class);
    vzwspec.setContent(vzwIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(attspec);

    tabHost.addTab(sprspec);

    tabHost.addTab(vzwspec);
}
 }
```

Here is my individual.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@color/background1"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <include layout="@layout/title_bar" />
 <include layout="@layout/tabs" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

If there is any other code that needs to be post please let me know and thanks for the assistance

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't have to extend TabActivity to use tabs in Android. Take a look at the iosched app source code where they do something similar to what you want.

Comment: I have looked through the iosched but its a tad bit above my level right now but thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by doing the following. Even though there is probably a better way here is what I've got

Individual.java

```
 package com.ondrovic.bbym;

 import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TabHost;
 import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

 public class Individual extends Dashboard {
     TabHost mTabs;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.individual);
    setTitleFromActivityLabel(R.id.title_text);

    mTabs = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mTabs.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

    TabSpec attspec = mTabs.newTabSpec("ATT");
    attspec.setIndicator("AT&T", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_att_tab));
    Intent attIntent = new Intent(this, Individual_ATT.class);
    attspec.setContent(attIntent);

    TabSpec sprintspec = mTabs.newTabSpec("SPRINT");
    sprintspec.setIndicator("SPRINT", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_sprint_tab));
    Intent sprintIntent = new Intent(this, Individual_SPRINT.class);
    sprintspec.setContent(sprintIntent);

    TabSpec verizonspec = mTabs.newTabSpec("VERIZON");
    verizonspec.setIndicator("VERIZON", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_verizon_tab));
    Intent verizonIntent = new Intent(this, Individual_ATT.class);
    verizonspec.setContent(verizonIntent);

    mTabs.addTab(attspec);
    mTabs.addTab(sprintspec);
    mTabs.addTab(verizonspec);
}
}
```

Here's the result everything is working :-)

[image]